# Why this is giving me error in the typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I copy a component from a webpage.

It was something like this

```
export default class ShowMore extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) { //ERROR HERE
    super(props);

    this.wrapper = React.createRef(); //ERROR HERE
    this.state = {
      expand: false,
      expandable: true,
      height: '0px',
      mounted: false,
    };

    this._handleResize = () => this.handleResize; //ERROR HERE
  }
```

as you can see this is not a typescript code.

So I try to convert it to typescript but it still giving me error.

I have some experience with class component but i don't have experience with `typescript && class component` so i am confused right now.

From my understanding as long as i give the `type` or `interface` to the `props`, The error should goes away but it does not, here is the updated code.

```
interface SeeMoreProps {
  wrapper: any;
  handleResize: any;
}

export default class ShowMore extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props: SeeMoreProps) { //This error goes away
    super(props);

    this.wrapper = React.createRef(); // Error(Property 'wrapper' does not exist on type 'ShowMore')
    this.state = {
      expand: false,
      expandable: true,
      height: '0px',
      mounted: false,
    };

    this._handleResize = () => this.handleResize; //Property '_handleResize' does not exist on type 'ShowMore'. Did you mean 'handleResize'?
  }
```

Can someone help explain why my interface not working in this case?

Comment: Please [edit] the title to be more descriptive of your issue, as described in [ask].

Answer (score 2):

`this.wrapper` should be in the scope of the class component.

Here the updated code:

```
interface SeeMoreProps {
  wrapper: any;
  handleResize: any;
}

export default class ShowMore extends React.PureComponent {
  //This is the scope of the class component
  wrapper: unknown;
  _handleResize: unknown;
  constructor(props: SeeMoreProps) { 
    super(props);

    this.wrapper = React.createRef(); 
    this.state = {
      expand: false,
      expandable: true,
      height: '0px',
      mounted: false,
    };

    this._handleResize = () => props.handleResize; //you need to pass 
handleResize from props.handleResize;
  }
```